# UIPopoverControllerDelegate methods never being called

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

This has me scratching my head. I have a view controller that implements `UIPopoverControllerDelegate`:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UIPopoverControllerDelegate> {
```

It implements the methods in that protocol, like so:

```
- (bool)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover
{
    NSLog(@"THIS IS NEVER CALLED");    
    return true;
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover
{
    NSLog(@"THIS IS ALSO NEVER CALLED");
}
```

I create the view controller to be shown in a popover, and the popover controller, like so:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender
{
    self.popoverViewController = [[MyPopoverViewController alloc] init];
    self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverViewController];
    self.popover.delegate = self;

    CGRect frame = button.frame;
    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

I'm very clearly setting `popover.delegate = self`. *HOWEVER*, the `popoverViewController` delegate methods I've implemented are never being called.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Note, I'm using ARC & LLVM.

Comment: Is the popover displaying correctly?

Comment: Yes - it is displaying correctly, & dismissing - just not invoking delegate methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your delegate method implementations are incorrect.  Try

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
```

rather than 
    - (bool)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover

and

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
```

rather than

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover
```

it's important that you get the method names and parameters correct, otherwise they will not be called.

Good luck!

Comment: Ahhh... yep, that was it. Ah, the joys of finding out your answer is something very simple that you overlooked...

Comment: No worries. Sometimes it just takes another pair of eyes!